# Boreir by non-food items?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, borer-separating

Rabbi Avrohom Davis' translation of the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch has a footnote on the boreir paragraph in the chapter on melachos forbidden on Shabbos that says that the majority of poskim rule that boreir applies also by non-food items. I understand that not all poskim rule this way. Who are the poskim who say that boreir does not apply by non-food items?

Answer (score 2):

On the Hebrew Wikipedia entry for [Borer](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A8), several opinions are cited for those of the opinion that Borer does not apply by non-food items (**see [footnote #7](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A8#cite_note-7)**):

> 1) **מהר"י עייא"ש בשו"ת בית יהודה** - Mahari Ayash in "Sheilos v'Teshuvos Beis Yehuda"
>
> 2) **האור שמח בפירושו על הרמב"ם** - Ohr Sameach in his commentary on the Rambam
>
> 3) See *Sefer* **Minchas Yaakov 2:17** for what poskim in this day and age say

The article also cites the opinion of [Rabbi Shimon Greenfeld](https://www.geni.com/people/Rabbi-Shimon-Greenfeld-Mahrshag-Zt-l/6000000003645129801) (1860-1930) who believes that the prohibition of Borer **does not** apply to books.

**R' Greenfield** is quoted in [footnote #9](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A8#cite_ref-9)--from his sefer  **שו"ת מהרש"ג חלק ג' סימן נ"ד - נ"ז**-- as saying:

> סבור שאין בספרים משום איסור ברירה. הוא מנמק זאת בסברא עצמית: מכיוון שלספרים יש מקום קבוע בארון, ולאחרי השימוש בהם הוא מחזיר אותם לארון, לא שייך לקרות הפרדת הספר מהארון בשם הפרדת אוכל מפסולת, שכן אין דרך המפריד אוכל מפסולת להחזיר אותו לאחר השימוש לערב בתוך הפסולת, ומכאן שאין הפרדת הספרים מהספרים שסמוך למקומם בארון קרוי בשם אוכל מתוך פסולת.
>
> Since the books have a fixed place on a bookshelf, and after a book is used it's returned to the bookshelf, this removing of a book from a bookshelf is not comparable to removing food from the chaff(waste) since there is no way to separate food from waste, and then after "using" the food to return the food to it's initial state- ie mixed together with the chaff(waste).

However, **Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach** ([footnote #10](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A8#cite_ref-10)) rejects this view, and he rules that it is necessary to be stringent.